# Server Sent Event and ASP Classic (with Javascript)

Tags: asp-classic, server-sent-events

So I'm trying to implement some server side event in ASP Classic. This is because I can't do push notifications with ASP Classic. It consists of a Javascript and ASP code. The idea is to send a notice in the form of a sound when you have a new message.

ASP Code in a file named "poller.asp". It polls the private messages and if a new message is found, it executes this code. The code is basically the 'event' that makes up the server event.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream"
Response.Expires = -1
response.write ("retry: 10000") & vbcrlf
Response.Write("data: New Mail" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf )
Response.Flush()
```

and the Javascript:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html><body>
    <div id="result"></div>

  <script src="/poller/audio-fx.js"></script>
  <script>
var pool = AudioFX('/poller/alert',
  { formats: ['mp3'], volume: 0.8, autoplay: false });

if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource("/poller/poller.asp");
  source.onmessage = function(event) { 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
pool.play();
  }
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So this code WORKS in that it receives a message when a new private message is detected. It reads it from the stream (poller.asp). There are two issues however:
1) This only works if a new message exists from the time the script is run. If there's no new messages, the stream seems to close. Let's say there are no new messages, then someone sends me one, nothing happens. If there is a new message when I run the script, it works, but if I delete it and receive another one, it also doesn't notify me. I suspect this is something to do with the stream closing.

2) You will notice the Audio-FX. JS and the pool.play. This plays a short mp3 "You have a new message". The issue is that it fails on the first two tries. Say I have a new message waiting. It will say "New Mail" as per the
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "
"
but only after doing so twice, will it play the audio. I think maybe it's a buffering issue. As it plays every time thereafter.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Interesting idea but I don't think your going to get Classic ASP to behave like a web socket. Instead you could try a simplier approach of using a `setInterval()` to call the ASP page via AJAX request at a regular interval. For it to work you'll probably need to remodel the ASP page to return a simple JSON response and then parse that client side.